# Loop cut inside a circle creates dots, not nested circles

Tags: modeling, loop, looping

So, I'm following [this](https://youtu.be/SH6fhETqRKc?t=1375) tutorial on YT, and got stuck when trying to add loop cuts inside a circle. What I've done is adding a circle, in Edit mode extruded it inward and merged at centre. Then I need to add circle loop cuts inside this big circle, but the loop cut tool only creates dots.
I've tried the inset tool, but it didn't do anything, switching to face mode also didn't help. Also tried to subdivide the mesh, no result.[image: my mesh]

[image: that's what ctrl+r does]

[image: what I' trying to achieve]
I'm running a Blender 3.2.0 version on Windows 10.
If you could help me with this issue, I'd be very grateful, becuse I'm a newbie and such problems are still a bit tricky for me to solve on my own.

Comment: As long as you only have the circle on the outside connected to the center vertex, the _Loop Cut_ tool will not work as you expect it because it needs quads, whereas each face in your geometry is a triangle. That's why you need to inset it first before you try do a loop cut. If insetting doesn't work with your mesh, then there is something wrong, perhaps double vertices because of incorrect extruding or twice or whatever, without the blend file it's hard to guess.

Comment: Insetting is not what they do in the tutorial. Easiest thing would be to simply do it again from scratch (it's not that many steps). Add a circle, E to extrude and directly press S to scale it down. Then left-click or Enter to confirm the scaled down circle. With the new vertices selected, hit E again and directly right-click to abort the extrude, with the vertices still selected hit M > Merge > At Center. Now you can loop cut the rest.

Comment: Oh, for the _Inset_ tool not working: did you use it correctly? You are working in _Vertex Select_ mode as the screenshot shows, have you only selected the outer circle vertices? Because insetting works on faces, not vertices - so you have to select the center vertex as well in order to have all faces selected. Then the _Inset_ tool should work or as I commented above, there is something else wrong with your mesh which cannot be easily determined by the screenshot.

Comment: Rewatching the tutorial did really help, I just had to click E one more time before merging the triangles. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, no offense - it's just normal that beginners sometimes don't notice everything that's said and done in a tutorial, so rewatching does help a lot. Of course there are also bad tutorials out there or some that say "for beginners" but lack explaining well or thoroughly enough for beginners to follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> loop-cut and slide navigates its way through a mesh by following quad face-rings.(You can think of it as walking between railway-tracks, and cutting through the sleepers). As it stands, your circle is a fan of triangles. No quads, nowhere to go.

You can fix that by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> bevelling the central vertex with one segment. Now your circle is a face-ring of quads around a central n-gon, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> will work.

Comment: Or just following the tutorial would work, too ;)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann oops, I didn't bother :) The general point is not a bad one to make.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it's quite often that people do not follow tutorials accurately enough. And I sometimes see it in answers here, although a solution is given, in some cases if it's different from the way in the tutorial it might make problems in further steps. And I think it's inept not pointing people to where the error was in the first place. But that's just me :)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Fair enough. I should have watched it to be sure. I will consider my wrist to have been gently slapped :D.

Comment: You naughty boy :D  I'm often too lazy myself to watch linked tutorials (especially if they are not linked to the timecode of interest), but sometimes I'm just curious to see if it was so misunderstandingly explained to give a wrong result. Because I know, sometimes one can pay as much attention as possible but still not get it when the tut is unclear.

Comment: @Gordon I just have watched it. II's a very nicely paced and thought out toot! :)

Comment: Yeah, just needed to watch more carefully and redo the whole circle thing. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to do this:

[image: Circle in circle 2]

To achieve this perform the following:

1. Create a circle (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd>, *Mesh > Circle*)
2. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* and ensure all vertices are selected
3. Extrude (E) along Z axis (Z then drag upward) a bit
4. Confirm and *Extrude*  <kbd>E</kbd> again
5. Right click to cancel This is important otherwise your merge point will likely be at a height you don't want.
6. Merge at center with  <kbd>M</kbd>
7. From top down view ( <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>), select circle vertices
8. Extrude again ( <kbd>E</kbd>) and confirm without moving your mouse
9. Immediately scale ( <kbd>S</kbd>) to desired size.

If you are instead trying to do this:

[image: Circle inside Circle]

To achieve this perform the following:

1. Create a circle (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd>, *Mesh > Circle*)
2. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* and ensure all vertices are selected
3. Extrude ( <kbd>E</kbd>) along Z axis (<kbd>Z</kbd> then drag upward) a bit
4. Confirm and Extrude ( <kbd>E</kbd>) again
5. <kbd>Right Click</kbd>  to cancel. This is important otherwise your merge point will likely be at a height you don't want.
6. Merge at center (<kbd>M</kbd>)
7. From top down view ( <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>), select circle vertices
8. <kbd>Right Click</kbd>, then subdivide
9. From top down view ( <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>), select new circle inner vertices
10. Scale ( <kbd>S</kbd>) to desired size.